# Limit on size of stl stack object

Tags: c++, stl, stack

Is there any limit on the size of a `std::stack`?

I am using a `std::stack<std::pair<int,std::string>>` as my stack, and when the number of entries exceeds roughly 1 million, I am getting a runtime error.

Is this due to a restriction on the size of `std::stack`?

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons for the runtime error. Post your code.

Comment: @erosenin: It looks more like your stack allocated `long` buffer is the cause; particularly given that you gave it a size of one million. Typical implementation limits for automatic storage ("the stack") are in the realm of 1MB (Windows) to 8MB (Linux, most Unix). Assuming `long` is 8 bytes on this platform, 1 million * 8 bytes = 8MB, which just about blows the limit on most Unixes. Use dynamic memory allocation instead of an array in automatic storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::stack` is a container adapter. It is merely a front for some other container, that makes it look like a stack. Consider that `std::vector` can be treated like a stack if you replace the name `push` with `push_back` and the name `pop` with `pop_back`. Thus, any size limits or similar are going to be the result of the backing container, not `std::stack`.

The default backing container for `std::stack` is `std::deque` (`N3376 23.6.5.2 [stack.defn]`). The standard requires that `std::deque` provide a `max_size` member function (`N3376 23.3.3.1 [deque.overview]/2`), which tells you the maximum number of elements that `std::deque` can hold according to implementation limits. This will typically be something like `std::numeric_limits<std::deque<t>::size_type>::max()`.

However, it is more likely that you are either running into machine memory limits, or have some bug elsewhere in your application causing the runtime error.

Comment: Yes i checked with random inputs I was getting a SIGXFSZ error so it was file size limit that was causing the error http://ideone.com/0McrLi

Answer (score 0):

Underlying container of `std::stack` container adapter placed in `protected` section and [can be accessed by name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) `c` (from derived classes by means of full qualificated name or by introducing into class namespace using `using` derective).
Default underlying container is `std::deque`. `std::deque`, `std::list` or `std::vector`. All of them provides `max_size()` member function, returning maximum size avaliable to allocate yet.
[Authoritative source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/max_size) WRT `max_size()` member function of the mentioned containers said:

> **Notes**
>
> This value is typically equal to std::numeric_limits::max(), and reflects the theoretical limit on the size of the container. At runtime, the size of the container may be limited to a value smaller than max_size() by the amount of RAM available.

So, returning value of `max_size()`'s smart implementation can rely on RAM avaliable to allocate.

To access `std::stack<>::c.max_size()` one should write a derived from `std::stack<>` class as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

#include <cstdlib>


template< typename type >
struct my_stack
    : std::stack< type >
{

    using base = std::stack< type >;
    using base::base;
    using base::operator =;

    std::size_t
    max_size() const
    {
        return base::c.max_size();
    }

};

int
main()
{
    my_stack< int > s;
    std::cout << s.max_size() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```